# android studio 3.3.1 color..xml Error: Can't determine type for tag '<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

Tags: android, android-xml

I have a project that was working perfect in the last version of Android Studio. I decided to upgrade to the version 3.3.1, and now the color.xml present a error, try to rebuild, clean,  even change the minSdkVersion, nothing work.

The following is the original code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3e2723</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#3e2723</color>
    <color name="blackTransparent">#ad000000</color>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:color="#ffcc0000"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:color="#ff669900"/>
</selector>

</resources>
```

the error msg is

```
...\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml: Error: Can't determine type for tag '<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

I'll really appreciate any feedback in this issue

Comment: Same error happens to me.  Just upgraded the gradle to the latest (as per the warning message!) and zap! won't even compile anymore.  Thanks, Google!

Comment: Thx for your advise, but i already have the lastest version 4.10.1. best regards

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside a drawable resource file and set the background of whatever view (e.g. button, image) to this drawable resource. It'll work!

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:color="#ffcc0000"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:color="#ff669900"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: thx for your prompt response. Now works again, but wonder why it was working no problem for almost a year and now since I upgrade the android Studio stop working?

Comment: I don't know about that, maybe Android Studio made some changes upon updation. Though I always use selector tag inside drawable resource to implement custom design on buttons and imageviews. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 0):

a `ColorStateList` `selector` does not belong inside a `resources` node.

you have to put that into an extra file.

Comment: thx for your prompt response.  maybe don't belongs there, but was working fine, until I upgrade the android studio.

Comment: @QQapps18 this was always illegal - while now  it is being enforced (along a few other things)... while my answer provides an easy solution to fix it. "it once worked", this is anything but a valid argument... because this does not help, at all. the other answer suggested about the same, while I think I was a tad quicker. please accept the answer if it helps.